# add headers to file_get_contents in php

Tags: php

I am completely new PHP and want a client program to call an URL web service.I am using file_get_content to get the data.How do add additional headers to the request made using file_get_content.

I also was thinking of using cURL. I wanted to know how cURL can be used to do a GET request.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: Just FYI, the PHP documentation is actually VERY useful, unlike most documentation. It includes helpful examples for every function. A simple question like this can be solved using the documentation ;)

Comment: @Kranu thanks for the suggestion. I had never touched PHP before and  was a little apprehensive due to client request. I simply <3 language specific unwanted URGENT client requests. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add headers to `file_get_contents`, it takes a parameter called `context` that can be used for that:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => "Host: www.example.com\r\n" .
                    "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/", false, $context);
```

Answer (score 2):

As for cURL, the basic example from the [PHP manual](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) shows you how to perform a GET request:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: You can. It's in the documentation ^_^

Comment: Remove that first line and I'll give you +1 for a decent cURL-example.