# Force curl to download page as browser

Tags: php, curl

How to force curl (with) PHP to download page as browser? The page I want to download is a price comparator, for e.g. http://www.ceneo.pl/22416171. It's public, anybody can access site.

To check if the curl downloading is even possible, I typed on my Debian-based local server

`curl http://www.ceneo.pl/22416171`

And it worked perfectly. But I do need to use it on my Virtual PHP-Apache serv, so I need to use PHP to do it.

While trying to download page as PHP-based curl, it gives me nothing, opposite to shell curl.
Why? How can I get the right content on PHP?

Tried:

```
                        <?php
                        $curl = curl_init(http://www.ceneo.pl/22416171);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                        array(
                        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0',
                        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                        'Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
                        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                        'p3p: CP="NOI CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR BUS IND UNI COM NAV INT"',
                        'Vary: Accept-Encoding',
                        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
                        'Cache-Control: private'
                        ));



                        $body = curl_exec($curl);
                        curl_close($curl);

                        echo $body;
                        ?>
```

I tried also to use

`<?php exec(curl http://www.ceneo.pl/22416171); ?>`

But it gave

`curl: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

This is how you do it:

**test.php**

```
<?php

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.ceneo.pl/22416171");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//set headers
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    //'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'p3p: CP="NOI CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR BUS IND UNI COM NAV INT"',
    'Vary: Accept-Encoding',
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
    'Cache-Control: private'
));

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

// debug
echo $output;
```

Demo of it working (only the html output from the site is retrieved):

[image]

Comment: What did you actually change? This reads like a game of spot-the-difference.

Comment: Few changes actually. `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is defined twice, so i removed one. curl init was wrong (the url wasn't encapsulated in single/double quotes) - so i used `CURLOPT_URL` to set it. finally i commented out one of his header `Accept-Encoding` and removed `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` - this was returning some garbled up text.

Comment: Your script showed actually nothing on my server. Without any errors.

Tried on another Virtual Server, and worked fine... Any ideas why?

In URL place, there was a variable, sorry for that...

Comment: Your server must be using outdated curl library. What version of PHP are you using on your server and have you installed the correct `php_curl` lib? What operating system are you running on your server?

Comment: P.S. Do you really need curl? why don't you do this instead: `echo file_get_contents('http://www.ceneo.pl/22416171');`. If you want to add headers to the `file_get_contents` function, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4779665/2332336